# How to check if a query is limited?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, limit

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and I would like to check if a query is limited. That is:

```
Article.where(...).limit(10) # This is a limited query
Article.where(...)           # This is not a limited query
```

Is there a way to check if the `limit` is set?

---

*Note*: I would like to check the `limit` in order to dynamically set it for a query if that is not set yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the Arel object's `limit`.

```
Article.where(...).limit(10).arel.limit.present?  # true
Article.where(...).arel.limit.present?            # false
```

Comment: How can I remove the `limit` clause from the query expression?

Comment: You can just pass another `limit` call, like `limit(nil)`. `Article.where(...).limit(10).limit(nil)`